# Turn off forcing www

Tags: apache-2.2, bind

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enable acess without WWW on Ubuntu](https://serverfault.com/questions/131671/enable-acess-without-www-on-ubuntu)

I have a 'clean' CentOS system with webmin, running Apache2 and BindDNS.

When I try accessing the domain without www, I get instantly redirected to www.domain.name, as the Firebug Net console screenshot below displays

http://pokit.etf.ba/upload/pokit141661fa46b11782745bb974d5140004.png

What I need to know is; which are the most often reasons for this?

If you need any more info, cfg or log files, please let me know

Comment: I believe this is not a problem with your server but with your browser. What browser and OS are you using?

Comment: Look at the related questions at the lower right of this page.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely scenario is a vhost configuration in apache set to something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName non-www-domain.com
    ServerAlias potential.com
    ServerAlias other-names.com

    Redirect / http://www.domain.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

However I do wonder if it's your browser or DNS.

Check if `domain.com` and `www.domain.com` resolve to the same IP, if not then you might be looking at the wrong server. If one doesn't resolve then it's certainly the browser doing the redirect.